# Xamarin.Android application crashes when power saving mode is enabled

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, crash, doze

I've got a serious problem with power saving mode on Android. My application crashes when power saving mode is enabled. The problem manifests itself on Samsung Galaxy phones (or on any phone/emulator with AOSP or LineageOS), but it never happened on Meizu or Xiaomi (due to their own battery optimizations, I guess; the code below always returns false, doesn't matter if I turned on power saving mode on these phones).

1st test: power saving mode disabled, app works great.

2nd test: power saving mode enabled, app not whitelisted, app crashes on launch.

3rd test: power saving mode disabled, app started and minimized; when I enable power saving mode, app asks me to add itself to white list; even if I add app to the white list, app still may crash.

4th test: power saving mode enabled, app whitelisted; app works partly, crashes or freezes randomly.

I know about Doze mode and enabled REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission in AndroidManifest.xml. Here's my code that checks if power saving mode is enabled and if app is in the white list. But my app crashes before this code being reached (except one issue that I've described).

PowerWorker.cs

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BSWApp.Droid.PowerWorker))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    class PowerWorker : IPowerWorker
    {
        public bool IsInPowerSavingMode()
        {
            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
            bool isPowerSaveMode = powerManager.IsPowerSaveMode;
            return isPowerSaveMode;
        }

        public bool IsInWhiteList(string packageName)
        {
            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
            bool isInWhiteList = powerManager.IsIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName);
            return isInWhiteList;
        }

        public void RequestWhiteList(string packageName)
        {
            Application.Context.StartActivity(new Intent(Provider.Settings.ActionRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations, Net.Uri.Parse("package:"+packageName)));
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat from crash moment:

```
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime: Process: [hidden], PID: 1511
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:   at MyApp.Handlers.MessageHandler+<DisplayConfirmation>d__3.MoveNext () [0x00014] in <bf9ac05a02a44989a618d26fad48d12d>:0
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:   at MyApp.ViewModels.PowerWorkerViewModel+<LaunchPowerSettings>d__1.MoveNext () [0x0006e] in <bf9ac05a02a44989a618d26fad48d12d>:0
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <fe08c003e91342eb83df1ca48302ddbb>:0
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:   at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <ad2f15102b3a4d36b40e9b0cbc11c376>:0
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <ad2f15102b3a4d36b40e9b0cbc11c376>:0
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <ad2f15102b3a4d36b40e9b0cbc11c376>:0
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.17(intptr,intptr)
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:        at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:        at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
01-31 02:31:58.015  1511  1511 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
01-31 02:31:58.016   534   546 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity [hidden]/md5be088b8fe6dd8127a24806968ac5b197.MainActivity
```

No matter where I try to run it from (I tried from App.cs (shared code) and from MainActivity.cs (Android local code)), I still getting same result. I expected that app will ask user to add application to the whitelist, but in fact even if user did it, it doesn't matter, 'cause app still may crash even if whitelisted. So I'm completely confused what to do.

Comment: you need to get the crash log to know why it crashes.

Comment: what are you trying to do that is making the app crash? upload data? download data? polling sensors continuously? also did you check logcat?

Comment: please put the logcat in your question-click edit. System.NullReferenceException means you're trying to use a value that isn't assigned. put some checks in your code

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan OK, did it. I know what NullReferenceException means. It seems odd to me that this exception is being thrown only when I turn on power saving mode.

Comment: Have you tried to run this code in native android? If you will have same issue?